# Storing derived objects in a vector by base class, and upon removal return them to derived objects

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ so I decided to create a card game. I would like to stored derived card objects as a Card* in a vector. When someone draws a card I want to take the first object from the vector and return it. Here is where things get tricky, when doing this I want to convert it back from Card* to its original derived type. I was reading that it is impossible to downcast in c++ without an explicit cast and I wanted to either reaffirm this or find a solution.

Card class

```
class Card
{
public:
    int Cost;
    string Name;
    string Description;

    Card() {}
    Card(int Cost, string Name, string Description) : Cost(Cost), Name(Name), Description(Description) {}
};
```

Soul Class

```
class Soul : public Card
{
public:
    int Attack;
    int Defense;

    Soul(int Cost, string Name, string Description, int Attack, int Defense) :Card(Cost, Name, Description), Attack(Attack), Defense(Defense) {}
    void Attacking(Soul* DefendingSoul);
};
```

and finally an example of a specific card class

```
class Fire_Spirit : public Soul
{
public:
    Fire_Spirit() : Soul(1, "Fire Spirit", "A lonely spirit born from the inferno.", 2, 1) {}
    ~Fire_Spirit();
};
```

Deck Class

```
class Deck
{
public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
    Card* Draw();
    void Shuffle();
    void Add(Card* cardToAdd);
    void PrintDeck();
    static vector<Card*> Cards;
};
```

Draw method

```
auto Deck::Draw() -> Card*
{
    auto temp = Cards.front();
    Cards.erase(Cards.begin());

    return temp;
}
```

Ideally I would just like to return auto here but I read that I need to define the return type of auto for methods (I would LOVE to be shown otherwise)

I want to go from Card* to Fire_Spirit(*?) or any other specific card class. I know I can do a huge switch statement, but there has to be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the feedback provided in the comments, I would go with a solution like this:

```
class Card {
private:
    CardKind kind_;
    std::fucntion<void (Card &)> attack_;
    std::function<void (Card &)> effectFunc_;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any> properties;

    Card(CardKind kind, std::function<void (Card &)> attackFunc,
         std::function<void (Card &)> effectFunc);
};
```

Comment: I will look into this some more. Thank you very much, you've been very helpful!

Comment: In fact now u can have collections of triplets (kind, effectfunc, attackfunc) and store in some associative container. These can be used to construct ur card types. Much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Storing in containers by pointer makes type information lost at the time you put your type in the container. The point of type erasure is precisely to treat elements in a uniform way, and a class hierarchy does that.

If you want to have the type information back, you will need to ask the runtime with `typeid(my_var)` or `dynamic_cast`. *Make sure that your base class has a virtual destructor*. This will give you the original type:

```
auto temp = cards.front();
if (typeid(temp) == typeid(MyDerivedCard)) {

}
else if (...) {

}
```

or

```
if ((MyDerivedCard * c = dynamic_cast<MyDerivedCard>(temp)) != nullptr) {
//Use derived
}
...
```

P.S.: You could use `std::unique_ptr<Card>` to store the cards. They will delete the memory automatically and make ownership clear. Learn about it at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: But if I follow this won't I end up with a huge if/else or switch statement? I should have made this more clear but I intend there to be lots of cards all with their own class. Think magic the gathering or hearthstone amount of cards.

Comment: I recommend you to change your design before you have a million classes (I played Magic some time ago :D). Store the information more uniformly, do not use class hierarchies.

Comment: You could also use function registration per class and other tricks but that is going to complicate things a lot.

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve exactly, from a design point of view, maybe I can help. Why do you want to recover the original type exactly?

Comment: How would you recommend storing card information (Name, cost, type, attack, defense, etc, etc)? I want the original type because then I can just call a function on that object like effect() and it will have unqiue logic in the effect to affect the board. Essentially I want <cardwhatever>.Attack or .Effect() and handle things logically. I wanted a million classes because I only need a generic factory (assuming this exists in c++...) to create all instances of the cards (like create all the instances of cards in the deck).

Comment: mmmh... my recommendation: use a single class Card and use std::function<> for Attack and Effect, store the type as a variable if you want also, all at construction. Example constructor: Card(Kind k, std::function<AttackSig> attack, std::function<EffectSig> effect). This way you can customize Effect and Attack based on the card Kind, you get rid of class hierarchies also, and can even make the Cards easily movable and/or copyable if it makes sense. Adding a new card type is simply a matter of adding a different Effect and Attack.

Comment: But some cards don't have certain attributes. There are cards similar to instants and enchantments that can't have attack or defense. There are also many one word effects (haste, trample, etc).

Comment: Some cards do not have some attributes: store attributes as an std::map<Key, std::experimental::any> OR boost::any. With the kind attribute you know the kind of card: in effect and attack you can get these attributes from the map and convert back to the attribute original type.

Comment: What if there was a property in the base card class that I could call and then construct an object of that type in a factory? So when I get the card I have a name, cost, description, and propertyid. Then I simply call my factory passing in the propertyid and have it return an object with that propertyid?

Comment: See my second answer below: with a design like that you can: detect kind, add/remove properties at runtime and customize Attack and Effect. I think it would serve well your purposes. You can augment it to your needs.